# For MOTU packaging, to try or to install Ubuntu?

Tags: testdrive

When using testdrive for Precise release, do you "install ubuntu" or "try ubuntu"?

Comment: You can go to try ubuntu and then if you like what you see you can install it as well from try mode.

Answer (score 1):

`Try ubuntu` is live mode for ubuntu. You will get a full working ubuntu running from CD\USB.

`Install ubuntu` is to start the procedure to install ubuntu on hard disk.

Live mode is used to see whether all hardware / software functionality is working fine before any installation. Changes are lost on reboot (while running from CD, i never tried from usb)

Choose modes as per your requirement. :)

Comment: Ok, but if I were to install ubuntu, would this replace my current OS? when I launch the Precise release, I don't want to have to keep seeing the Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu screen.  I'm guessing that if I install it,testdrive would immediately bring me to the Precise release only within the VM.  Correct me if I'm wrong; I'm still apprehensive.

Comment: Frankly speaking , your question is not clear. What you want to do? run ubuntu in Virtual machine (as you said something in VM) or install it as native OS. In VM you have nothing to worry about, you can install. In hard disk you can choose either dual boot (I am assuming you have something other than ubuntu ), you can choose to wipe out other OS and use ubuntu or upgrade ubuntu (if you are using old version of ubuntu). This may sound confusing to you but to get help correctly you need to describe what you actually want and what is current setup